# String manipulation questions

Tags: java, string

I have a string like "`C:\Program Files\Directory\Something.txt`" and I would like to convert it into "`C:\\Program Files\\Directory\\Something.txt`" So basically add `\` wherevever a `\` is found. Is the best way to approach this using `indexOf` and breaking the string into sustrings and then concatenating again or is there a more efficent way of doing this in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s = "C:/Program Files/Directory/Something.txt";
String s2 = s.replaceAll("/", "//");
// => "C://Program Files//Directory//Something.txt"
```

**[Edit]**

If the string has *backslashes* then it gets really fun since that is the regular expression escape character.  This should work:

```
String s = "C:\\Program Files\\Directory\\Something.txt";
s.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
// => "C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Directory\\\\Something.txt"
```

Note that's four backslashes in the regex (two pairs in sequence to get two literal backslashses) and then eight in the replacement string since backslashes are also escape characters for literal strings.

Comment: Ya I did try replace all but it was giving an error and it probably has to do with \ being an escape character" `String filePath = "C:\\Program files\\Directory\\Something.txt";
        System.out.println(filePath);
        String filePath2 = filePath.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");
        System.out.println(filePath2);`

Comment: the error to the above is **Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1**

Comment: If you're using *backslashes* then the story is different, since that character is special to regular expressions, as you mention in your comment.

Comment: ya my bad I mistyped the backslashes. So can we use replaceall still to overcome this somehow?

Comment: Actually as my friend just pointed out the \ is an escape character in both the String and in regex. Hence String.replaceall wasnt working. To achieve what I am trying to do I either have to do `String filePath2 = filePath.replace("\\", "\\\\");` which doesnt use regular expressions or do `String filePath2 = filePath.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\

Answer (score 1):

You could use the File.separator property to make it more cross-platform:

```
String input = "C:/Program Files/Directory/Something.txt";
String result = input.replaceAll(File.separator, File.separator + File.separator);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `String.replaceAll` for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "C:/Program Files/Directory/Something.txt";
str = str.replaceAll("/","//");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "C:/Program Files/Directory/Something.txt";
s = s.replace("/", "//");
```

This will replace all `/` in the string with `//`